# My Simple ListView app is leaking memory. What am I doing wrong?‏

Tags: java, android, listview, memory-leaks, listactivity

First off, I did post this to the android google group first but its moderated and I'm not sure how long itll take to show up there so hoping someone here can help.

I created a simple app with a ListView following the ListActivity
examples I found on the net.

The app has 2 activities with the first having a button to create the
second. When i hit the close button on the second activity I would
like it to release its memory (or at least allow it to be garbage
collected). Currently it will never release.

I must be doing something wrong here because the MyListActivity never
gets released. Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong with
the way my activities are created/destroyed? or if my usage of the
ListView is wrong?

Thanks.

My App as a zip - http://www.mediafire.com/?l26o5hz2bmbwk6j

Screen Shot of Eclipse MAT showing the list activity never releasing
memory - www.mediafire.com/?qr6ga0k

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {  
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listlayout);        
    ListAdapter ada = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GENRES);               
    setListAdapter(ada);    
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{                   
    super.onDestroy();
    System.gc();
}

public void ClickHandler(View target)
{
    switch (target.getId())
    {
        case R.id.LL_Btn1:
            finish();
            break;
    }
}   

private static final String[] GENRES = new String[] {
    "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama",
    "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"
};} 

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void ClickHandler(View target)
{
    switch (target.getId())
    {
        case R.id.M_Button01:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName(MyListActivity.class.getPackage().getName(), MyListActivity.class.getName());         
            startActivity(intent);  
            break;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Eh...I'm not downloading a zip, thanks.  Can you post relevant snippets?

Comment: What makes you think there's a leak? Android could keep your activity running for a long time unless it needs the memory.

Comment: The reason im sure it is a memory leak is that I can keep doing this until my application crashes, by opening the activity and closing it. It will not release the memory. Eclipse's MAT tool is showing a dependancy on mContext.

Comment: Have you tried to GC several times in DDMS before you generating the report?

Comment: Many many times. I am positive that this is leaking but I'm too new to android to tell why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse MAT was the cause. New Android Studio doesn't cause these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting rid of System.gc() and see what happens? Calling System.gc() is merely telling the VM to initiate garbage collection - there is no guarantee when it will be done.

Comment: System.gc does not cause memory leaks. yes it may not always release things instantly but it doesnt hurt to hint to the vm when to clean stuff.

Comment: I'm not saying System.gc causes memory leaks, just that its not good practice to rely on calling it to "magically" appear to resolve your memory leaks :)

Comment: system.gc() isn't there to try and fix the leak its there because its a good place to call it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, and its not generally recommended to do this, but the following will kill your process in onDestroy():

System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Put that in the onDestroy method. Now this may actually kill your main process if called from a child activity (havn't tested it).

WARNING: I generally don't recommend doing this as its a "hackly" way of doing it, but if you just need your app (or activity) to close upon exit then this will work. You still need to debug to find out why your app is staying open and eating memory.