# Destroy MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a MapActivity where you can switch between MapView (Google Maps) and OfflineMapView (my class, shows a map previously downloaded to SD card). When switching between maps I want to completely destroy and create the map views so that only one map view is in the memory. I want this for 2 reasons:

1. My OfflineMapView takes most of available memory for caching tiles.
2. Google MapView has some attached threads which I don't want running when OfflineMapView is visible.

I tried to remove the MapView from layout and null my reference to it but when I want to show it again I get an exception saying that MapActivity can have only one MapView.

**EDIT:**
The presence of Google MapView (visibility is set to GONE) doesn't have any effect on OfflineMapView FPS. I didn't get any OutOfMemoryErrors either.

Comment: Did you `finish()` the `MapActivity`?

Comment: No. I have a map selector at the top of my Activity - https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/cz.fhejl.pubtran.london/ss-3-320-480-160-2-7b9a7adb8d4c06ddd826ef8177959f2b05013739 Users can choose between different offline maps and I want to implement Google MapView as one of the options. When Google Map gets selected, I want to destroy the offline map (OfflineMapView) and create Google MapView. By "destroy" I mean stop threads, clear bitmap cache and remove from layout. When user switches back to offline map, the Google MapView should be destroyed similarly.

Comment: I edited my question with additional info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ActivityGroup` as your `Activity` class and have it start and stop sub-activities for each type of map. For example, to get the view for the Google Map:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GoogleMapActivity.class);
Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("google-map", intent);
View googleMapView = window.getDecorView();
container.addView(googleMapView);
```

to destroy it:

```
container.removeView(googleMapView);
getLocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities();
```

and do the same with your offline map. This should completely stop the `MapActivity` and it's threads.

Note that I have found `LocalActivityManager.destroyActivity()` to be buggy, so I used `LocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities()` in the example since it does work for this case.